# Problem with JavaScript Intellisense VScode [ts()]

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

**Hello!**
I have a `ts()` `JavaScript` Intellisense problem in vscode. 
When I type following lines:

```
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log(input.value);
});
```

I get an error that states that Property `"value"` not found in `type` Element.

**Please suggest me!**

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector()` will return an `Element` type by default, which does not have a `value` property. You need to tell TypeScript a more specific kind of element that you are expecting the query selector to return, as it cannot deduce this from the query string alone.

Given that you expect the query selector to return an HTML input element you would use `const input = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("#input");` to narrow down the return type of the query selector. A `value` property exists on this type so now you can use `input.value`.

More specifically `document.querySelector` is a generic function, generics are used when something, such as the return type of a function, can be of more than one type. You can read more about generics and its syntax in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using TypeScript. I'm getting this error in VSCode only but in browser, everything works fine

Comment: @SagarikaDas I'm having the same problem as you. Have you found a solution?